# detecting photo upload using facebook realtime updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, photo, subscriptions

I would like to know what objects and connections I need to subscribe to in order to receive notifications (facebook realtime update feature) when a user uploads a new photo whether in his albums, as a status update, or into a group.

This is not about the user profile picture but any photo the user shares on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook says the following at the Realtime Updates description (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ - Below "Types of Updates"):

***Note that you can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events.***

The only thing I could think of is that you subscribe to the ***feed*** connection and do some postprocessing to find out whether the post was related to a photo:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/feed?fields=id,link,type,link&since={YOUR_TIMESTAMP}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

You can derive the USER_ID from the POST coming from Facebook's Realtime Updates, the YOUR_TIMESTAMP can be something like the system time the POST was received minus 30 seconds, and the ACCESS_TOKEN needs to come from where you stored it once the User gave permissions to your app.

Then you can parse the resulting JSON for all array entries with *"type": "photo"* and you'll receive the posts who reference a photo.

You could then create a comma-separated list of the post_ids and use this in conjunction with a FQL query to get more details about the attached photos:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+post_id,+attachment,+created_time+from+stream+where+source_id+=+{USER_ID}+and+type+=+247+and+post_id+in+({POST_ID_LIST})&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Within the resulting JSON, you can find the AID and the PID of the photos, which you can use to get more info about the photos. Or you use the URLs you'll find in *images.src*

You can get all photo posts via FQL in the following way, but this is then not related to the Realtime Updates:

```
select post_id, attachment, created_time from stream where source_id = me() and type = 247 limit 100
```